# Tabs and image timed changing

Tags: javascript, html, django

I've a tab where I display tab content on the left side, but on refresh, the tab current page doesn't stay, instead it goes back to the home Link.

Secondly, on The tabcontent, I've images on my Django database, were I display them on my template using the forloop, but I want to change the images after a given time. Below is my code for better understanding..

Js

```
// Sidebar functionality
  function openLinks(links){
    var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    x[i].style.display = "none";

  }

    document.getElementById(links).style.display = "block";
    }

// Changing Images

 var divs = $('#men .column');
  (function cycle(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length);
      divs.removeClass('active')
      .eq(index).addClass('active');
      cycle();    
    },500);
  })();
```

My HTML

```
<div class="sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#/home" class="tablinks" onclick="openLinks('home')">
          <span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-home" aria-hidden=True></i></span>
          <span class="title">Home</span>
        </a></li>

        <li><a href="#/men" class="tablinks" history="true" onclick="openLinks('men')">
          <span class="icon"><span class="icon"><i class="fas fa-male" aria-hidden=True></i></span>
          <span class="title">Men</span>
        </a></li>
</div>


<div id="home" class="tabcontent">
            {% for home in home %}
          <div class="column">
            <a href="{{men.get_men_absolute_url}}"><img src="{{home.pictures.url}}" style="width: 150px; height: 100px;"></a>
              </div>

  {% endfor %}
 
<div id="men" class="tabcontent" style="display: none;">
            {% for men in men %}
          <div class="column">
            <a href="{{men.get_men_absolute_url}}"><img src="{{men.men_pictures.url}}" style="width: 150px; height: 100px;"></a>
              </div>
{% endfor %}

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML there is no {% endfor %} on the forloops. Is this the full HTML cause Django would normally fall over without those in place?

Comment: I've effected the changes... Thanks